# Xamarin Android bind and use Java library in Visual Studio

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, binding

I want to add this Floating action button library from github into my Visual Studio project: 
https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

I followed this description with suggested adding a Binding Library (Android).
(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/)

I tried the binding with a **.jar** and **.aar** files.
The files seems to be ok but during import i get following exception:

```
BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8601: No packages found
```

OR

```
JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class com/github/clans/fab/FloatingActionButton$1 : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/ViewOutlineProvider
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While SushiHangovers answer is correct in term for doing your own binding.
If however you just want to make use of Clans Floating Action Button library, you can easily install [FAB.XamarinAndroid via nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FAB.XamarinAndroid/) which has already done the binding for this library for you.

**Edit**

The [GitHub repo](https://github.com/fabionuno/FloatingActionButton-Xamarin.Android) where you can see how the binding project is structured.

Answer (score 1):

(That is one of the cleanest binding I done, usually you end up with a lot of transformation...)

- Start from Scratch, and create a new `Xamarin.Android` solution/project via template.
- Add Android Library Binding project to your solution.
- Add `fab-1.6.3.aar` to the `Jars` folder:

(I used the [direct link to Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.clans%7Cfab%7C1.6.3%7C) listed on the Github project site)

Note: Make sure that the `.arr` is flagged as a build action of `LibraryProjectZip` after adding it.

Build the Binding project, you should get a couple of warning about overrides but no errors.

- Go to your main `Xamarin.Android` app project and add a reference to the binding project.
- Open up your Resources/Layout/Main.axml file and replace the contents:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

- Build and Run it on your emulator, not sexy quite yet as there is no code populating anything but it works:

[image]

Note: I went ahead and imported *all* the resources from their github sample otherwise you will end up with lots of compile errors regarding missing resources if you start working with their sample xml layouts and code.

```
FloatingActionButton/sample/src/main/res:
anim            drawable-xxhdpi     mipmap-xhdpi
drawable        drawable-xxxhdpi    mipmap-xxhdpi
drawable-hdpi       layout          values
drawable-mdpi       menu            values-v21
drawable-v21        mipmap-hdpi     values-w820dp
drawable-xhdpi      mipmap-mdli
```

And converted enough of the Java code for the [MainActivity OnCreate](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/clans/fab/sample/MainActivity.java) and the Fragments to test the it and everything works that I tried:

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution and I get a little bit further --> it compiles now without any exception. Unfortunately during execution I get following exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton"

Comment: Did you add the Android Library Binding project to your main Android app as a project reference?

Comment: Yes - I followed your instructions. It's a little bit strange - the official file from Xamarin demo is working. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/ (textanalyzer.aar)

Comment: @CreateAHero np, Glad to see that you got it to work via the Nuget version